# Android frame layout stack displayed incorrectly on some devices

Tags: android, admob, android-framelayout

To be able to control ad presence even if phone is offline I put 
the admob ad into LinearLayout, which is in frame layout so the ad
will be show on the top of the game. On HTC Desire(2.2) the view appears correctly 
ad is on top of the screen, but on Samsung Galaxy SII(2.3.1) ad is underneath the game - 
it is not visible but if one presses on the area it will trigger ad action.

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/game"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Code loading the ad:

```
private void loadAds() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads);
    final AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADMOB_ID);
    layout.addView(adView);
    final AdRequest request = new AdRequest();  
    adView.loadAd(request);
}
```

Edit: Adding bringToFront() didn't help. On SII the ad in not completely hidden there is 
about 3-5px of top visible.

Edit 2: It turned out that the issue was caused by hiding ad layout in onCreate. Solution was to hide it via handler after onCreate was executed.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is include the ad in your layout, then toggle its visibility based on whether you want an ad to appear or not.

```
//To show the view
adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE);

//To hide the view
adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You could also try calling bringToFront() on your AdView with your current code.

Comment: bringToFront() didn't help. That is what I do. The problem that I am trying to solve here is to have an ad when there is no ad from ad mob when phone is offline.

Comment: That seems a bit confusing, the question seems to indicate that part of the ad is visible?  Or is that only blank space where the ad should be positioned? Also, is it possible that you have not retrieved and cached an ad on the SII before trying to display it (eg, do you use the app and view several apps while online, before switching to offline?)  Sorry that didn't help, and good luck!